# Scan multiple servers, all drives per server for a certain file type

Tags: powershell

Currently have the following script that I'm working on to poll AD for all servers on a domain, then scan each server for physical drives, then each drive for a certain file type.

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Servers,dc=domain,dc=local" -Filter * | Select -Exp Name | sort
$result = $servers | 
% { 
    write-host "$_"
    gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "DriveType = 3" |
    select-object DeviceID |
    % {
    write-host "$_"
        gci . -recurse -filter *.txt | select fullname,length,lastWriteTime
   }
}
$result | export-csv c:\files.csv -notype
```

This does grab each server, but seems to only grab the C and D drive of the first server and repeats that for each one.  There are a few servers in there that have E: and M: drives that are not being picked up.

There is output to the screen as far as server name and, seemingly incorrect drives, but the csv file is empty.

Comment: Hi, what about replacing `gci .` with `gci $_` ? I don't understand how `.` can work here.

Comment: Are you sure that drives M: and E: have `DriveType = 3`?

Answer (score 0):

For network drives or unknown, ramdisks and other drive types the DriveType will be different than 3.

The following DriveTypes can be found in the win32_logicaldisk:

- Unknown (0)
- No Root Directory (1)
- Removable Disk (2)
- Local Disk (3)
- Network Drive (4)
- Compact Disc (5)
- RAM Disk (6)

I suggest you try removing your filter and fetch the disks as following:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk
```

For more information on the win32_logicaldisk - see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx